# powershell regex issue with powershell 2 vs. powershell 5 end of line anchor

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

Given the following code:

```
$inputString = "`r`n#cmakedefine BREAK_THE_CODE`r`n"
$match = '(?m)^(.*?)#cmakedefine(.*?)$'
$replace = 'hello $1#undef$2 goodbye '
$retVal = $inputString -replace $match,$replace -join "`r`n"
Write-Host $retVal
```

Powershell 5 produces the following (expected) output:

```
hello #undef BREAK_THE_CODE goodbye
```

Powershell 2 produces the following (unexpected) output:

```
 goodbye def BREAK_THE_CODE
```

Anyone know why?  Or have a workaround.  I'm fine with using [regex::] if it buys me more consistency.  I need both versions to produce the same results.  For what it's worth, hello and goodbye are going to end up being `/*` and `*/` but I'm trying to avoid confusing the issue with anything that could be interpreted as a special character.

EDIT: Matt's answer below is detailing that both Powershell versions are producing the same output, `[CR][LF]hello #undef BREAK_THE_CODE[CR] goodbye [LF]`
and the apparent difference between the versions is actually ISE vs. not ISE and `Write-Host`.  So the root problem is here is that my regex was just broken, although I still don't know why that is.

I ended up with:

```
$match = "(?m)^(.*?)#cmakedefine([^\r\n]*)"
$replace = '/* $1#undef$2 */'
```

As a little sidebar, the help for the VS 2015 IDE (which almost definitely uses the same regex engine) lists `\r?$` as the proper end of line anchor:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

That anchor could be made to work by capturing the `\r` portion of it, which I initially did, but I prefered Wiktor's solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not have anything to do with regex or PS Version but with how `Write-Host` is dealing with that lonely carriage return in the *middle of the string*. I can also reproduce this in PowerShell 2.0 and 5.0 but **not ISE** since it is a different environment. You can reduce your findings to this statement.

```
write-host "Hello Matt`rBagel"
```

It should print "Hello Matt Bagel" but instead prints "Bagel Matt" the carriage return resets the host cursorposition and then continues typing. So it did print Hello Matt but then overwrote "Hello" with "Bagel".

[Wikipedias definition of CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) will help explain that this is  status by design when the control character is by itself.

> A carriage return, sometimes known as a cartridge return and often shortened to CR,  or return, is a control character or mechanism **used to reset a device's position to the beginning of a line of text.**

You would not see this if you just use `Write-Output` or just `$retVal` on the command line. Removing the lonely CR would also fix this.

```
write-host ("Hello Matt`rBagel" -replace "`r(?<!`n)")
```

The reason you have this issue is that it appears your `(.*?)$` is anchored on `` "`n" `` so the capture group is consuming the carriage return. If this is something you are seeing in your real data then you would need to account for it somehow.

Comment: Ahh, excellent.  This is helpful information, although I'm unfortunately in a function and Write-Output gets swallowed.

Comment: So that's the other problem.  I'm not sure why my regular expression is broken :)

Comment: Ah yes. Let me look at that realy quick

Comment: Presumably something like `\r?$` (I'm using \ to avoid fighting with stackoverflow) would work.  I just don't understand why it's necessary

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your [`'(?m)^(.*?)#cmakedefine(.*?)$'`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%28.*%3f%29%23cmakedefine%28.*%3f%29%24&i=%0d%0a%23cmakedefine+BREAK_THE_CODE%0d%0a) pattern is that the `.` symbol matches any char but an LF (a newline only), and `(?m)` modifier makes the `$` anchor match right before the LF, after a possible CR. That means, the CR symbol is present at the end of Capturing group 2.

Look at your string:

```
<CR><LF>
#cmakedefine BREAK_THE_CODE<CR><LF>
|------------- MATCH ---------|
||          |-----Group2------|
```

Group 1 value is empty, Group 2 contains  `BREAK_THE_CODE`. So, the CR becomes "lonely" as [Matt explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46821824/3832970).

Here is a possible fix, replace the last lazy dot pattern with `[^\r\n]*` that matches 0 or more chars other than CR and LF (and `$` becomes redundant then):

```
$match = '(?m)^(.*?)#cmakedefine([^\r\n]*)'
$replace = 'hello $1#undef$2 goodbye '
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28.*%3F%29%23cmakedefine%28%5B%5E%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%29&i=%0D%0A%23cmakedefine%20BREAK_THE_CODE%0D%0A&r=hello%20%241%23undef%242%20goodbye%20) (unfortunately, all the values in the table there are trimmed from whitespace, but it must work well now.)

Comment: Is this a typical issue with \r\n line endings?  I don't recall having run into it with other regex engines, but maybe I was working with linux line endings every time.

Comment: .NET is not the only one. E.g. [Python does the same](https://ideone.com/4O9fDD). However, it is [not the case with JS](https://jsfiddle.net/x4t16au3/).